# Instant search and ajax events

Tags: ajax, search

I want to make a search field for a form that automatically refreshes the form as you type with the answers that match the filter, like google does it.

I looked at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7 and the examples module for the ajax related stuff but I can't find all the possible ajax events listed. The only ones I know of are blur, keydown and keyup.

I thought keyup would do the trick but every time I type a letter in the textfield the ajax event will disable the textfield, only to let me type another letter after the ajax callback is finished. I can't use this.

I want something like the autocomplete Drupal incorporates, it doesn't block the textfield at every typed letter, but as far as I know the native autocomplete uses a combination of ajax events.

Can someone please give me an idea of how I can accomplish such a task?

Edit:
Just to be clear, I'm not looking to autocomplete suggestions, I know how to do that, I want to update a paged table of results with each letter typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Drupal Instant Search](https://drupal.org/project/instant), or [Finder](https://drupal.org/project/finder). Even if it isn't exactly what you want, it should be a good starting point.

Drupal Instant Search:

> It works as follows: The url for the instant is at /instant The user
>   types his search word, once he finishes typing (javascript keyup) the
>   module automatically submits the search word and returns the search
>   results. The search results are displayed at the same page of the
>   instant search.
>
> Instant search is also integrated with Top searches module. if Top
>   searches module exists, the instant search auto-completes top search
>   words.

Finder:

CHECK MODULE FIRST DUE TO THIS WARNING:

> This module is unsupported due to a security issue the maintainer
>   didn’t fix.